# Find command output doesn't give desire result

Tags: command-line, find

Create files

```
touch a1.txt a2.txt a3.txt
touch s1.mp3 s2.mp3 s3.mp3
```

then I do

```
find . -name "*.txt" -or -type f -print
```

And it's showing only `s1.mp3` `s2.mp3` `s3.mp3`.
Why it's not showing `.txt` files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the precedence of the operators: the *implicit* AND (`-a`) between `-type f` and `-print` has higher precedence than the OR (`-o`); your command is similar to

```
find . \( -name "*.txt" \) -or \( -type f -print \)
```

while you probably want

```
find . \( -name "*.txt" -or -type f \) -print
```

to print all the files.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence is only half of the answer. What matters is also how the rules for finishing the boolean expressions work. This soon gets a bit complicated, mostly becasue `find` uses sane defaults and is programmable at the same time.

To illustrate what I mean, here is another solution:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print -or -type f -print
```

this adds an explicit *action* to every end-point. And just:

```
]# find -name "*.txt" -or -type f
./p.txt
./s1.mp3
./a1.txt
```

also gets all files (including the non-regular "p.txt" entry). Here the default `-print` is outside any (sub-)expression and is applied for all branches.

After adding exactly one `-print`, you get "either...or":

```
]# find -name "*.txt" -print -or -type f 
./p.txt
./a1.txt

]# find -name "*.txt" -or -type f -print
./s1.mp3
```

No use deabating which is better - problem is the Q is very artificial (and also duplicate). If somebody wants to track down a `mkfifo pipe.txt`, a logical 'AND NOT' instead of 'OR' would make more semantic (and overall) sense.

For this, you need neither parens nor -print:

```
]# find -name "*.txt" -not -type f       
./p.txt
```